# My Mac mini's iTunes library does not appear in Home Sharing on my Macbook Air

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

I don't know why.

- My entire iTunes Library is on my Mac mini
- I've entered the same Apple ID in iTunes' Home Sharing on both computers
- My iPhone and iPad can use Home Sharing from my Mac mini's iTunes
- I open iTunes on my MBA and Home Sharing does not appear in the left sidebar
- I tried removing and re-entering my Home Sharing credentials on my MBA.  This did not help.

I've searched around for a solution but found nothing.  Does anyone have any experience or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go into `Preferences` and make sure you have `Shared Libraries` ticked in the `Show` section of the `General Preferences` pane.

You might also have the details hidden in the sidebar. If the sidebar has `SHARED` in grey writing with nothing under it then try placing the cursor to the right of the word (near the right edge of the pane) and either `Hide` or `Show` will appear, allowing you to toggle the list.